# Is it necessary to protect ATM pins against malware that has no access to the physical card?

Tags: malware, injection, atm

I understand that various types of malware [attempt to steal ATM pins](http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/evolution-banking-malwares-part-2/) .

Presumably the attackers have no access to the physical card, so what can they do with the pin?

In this case, is it needed to keep the pin secure? Or is this part of an attack that involves stealing the actual card?

Comment: The article itself explains that it's not just the PIN but the card number, too, along with the bank you use and your account information. In some cases, with this info they can create a physical card.